# Use a class in two different namespace

Tags: c#

How do use a class from namespace in other namespace?

```
namespace All
{
  class X
  {
    public static void Read() {}
  }
  class Y
  {
    public static void Write() {}
  }
}


namespace A
{
  namespace First{
     //use class X in namespace All here;
  }
}

namespace B
{
  namespace Second{
     //use class Y in namespace All here;
  }
}
```

i don't want copy paste code,is there a keyword in C# to reference the hole the class? use it here like

```
B.Second.Y.Write();
```

Comment: If you have you ever taken a look at an actual c# program you would have noticed some "using" statements, generally at the top of a file. I.e. `using A;` Another way is to prefix the type with its namespace as in `A.First`.

Comment: yes,i know that,but it just include that class. i don't know how use it,may you give an example?

Comment: `Y` isn't in namespace `Second`. `B.Second.Y ` won't work because of that.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Just add classes with methods inside of `First` and `Second` namespaces and you will be able to call `All.X.Read();` or `All.Y.Write();`
if the namespace is in different project, you need to reference the project as well.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot directly use other types as variable in a namespace

**So**

You may use those types (`X`, `Y`) in the types in those namespaces (`First`, `Second`). e.g

```
namespace All
{
    class X
    {
        public static void Read() { }
    }
    class Y
    {
        public static void Write() { }
    }
}


namespace A
{
    namespace First
    {
        //use class X in namespace All here;

    }
}

namespace B
{
    namespace Second
    {
        //use class Y in namespace All here;
        class MyClass
        {
            private All.X;   //HERE is the code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to have something like `B.Second.X` which is the same as `All.X` - so maybe he just wants a `class X : All.X` right in there

Comment: @CenaAv it may be better to clarify what do you mean by *use* in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the using Keyword

```
using A;
using B;
using All;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define namespace A & B as followed:

```
namespace All
{
    public class X
    {
        public static void Read() { }
    }
    public class Y
    {
        public static void Write() { }
    }
}


namespace A
{
    namespace First
    {
        public static class X
        {
            public static void Read()
            {
                All.X.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace B
{
    namespace Second
    {
        public static class Y
        {
            public static void Write()
            {
                All.Y.Write();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like so...

```
namespace CodeResearch.StackOverFlowTests
{
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines DebugStackOverFlow type
    /// </summary>
    public class DebugStackOverFlow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Tests debugging StackOverFlow questions
        /// </summary>
        public static void Test()
        {
            A.First.X.Read();
            B.Second.Y.Write();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
I have all of this defined in the same cs file.